# Jquery Mobile - fix header or footer

Tags: jquery-mobile

im trying to make fix footer and header like the header in this page:
http://breeze.pcollab.com/moby_preview/Blue/blog.html

but all i succeed doing is header and footer that are fix but when you rolling down it disappear and only when you stop rolling it comeback again.

*when i am talking about footer i mean navbar. like those:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using the current jQM 1.0.1 fixed header/footer, try using the test versions:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

This is what should be released in jQM 1.1 or at least very close to it

Comment: how do i use this instead of what i used? where can i find the new code or the things i need to change in order to use the test versions?

Comment: view the source and grab the test library links for jQM